# Firebase Cloud Functions / Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I was following the official firebase tutorial on promises (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA) but in my case, I cannot make it work.

```
const promise = userRef.push({text:text});

const promise2 = promise.then((snapshot) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: 'ok!'});
});

promise2.catch(error => {
    res.status(500).json({message: 'error'});
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Each then() should have its response in case something goes wrong, but that is why I am writing the promise2 catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `return` before sending the response.

```
const promise = userRef.push({text:text});

const promise2 = promise.then((snapshot) => {
    return res.status(200).json({message: 'ok!'});
});

promise2.catch(error => {
    return res.status(500).json({message: 'error'});
});
```

Also you can chain the promises as follows:

```
return userRef.push({text:text})
.then((snapshot) => {
    return res.status(200).json({message: 'ok!'});

}).catch(error => {
    return res.status(500).json({message: 'error'});
});
```