# How to grab json file from external url(PLACES API) using firebase functions

Tags: android, json, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-places-api

So, 
I want to send a request from my app to Firebase using cloud funtions and then process process url and send back JSON file from places api

WHAT I HAVE ALREADY DONE/HAVE=>
After Setting up the project in console and getting firebase CLI created a cloud function as follows

After following your comments
this is my full function code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const rp = require('request-promise');

exports.fetch = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {

    const url = req.url + '&key=MY_API_KEY';
    var options = {
        uri: url, // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
        json: true
    };  

    rp(options)
    .then(result => {
        console.log('Get response:' + response.statusCode);
        return res.type('application/json').send(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        // API call failed...
        return res.send({'Error': err});
    });

})
```

and in java class passed values like this

```
     private Task<String> addMessage(String url) {
            // Create the arguments to the callable function.
            Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("url", url);///PASSING VALUES HERE
            return mFunctions
                    .getHttpsCallable("fetch")
                    .call(data)
                    .continueWith(task -> 
(String) Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getData());
        }
```

Now What my problem is while deploying new function code with firebase CLI I am getting `16:8  error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return` as error

Can anyone guide me please..,

URL will be like this : 
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=17.4369681,78.4473887&radius=5000&type=airport&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY`

Here are the log details from console

```
2019-07-05T10:06:35.025308453Z D fetch: Function execution started
2019-07-05T10:06:35.265840608Z D fetch: Function execution took 241 ms, finished with status code: 200
2019-07-05T10:06:45.162Z I fetch: Get response:undefined
2019-07-05T10:06:46.062Z E fetch: Unhandled rejection
2019-07-05T10:06:46.062Z E fetch: TypeError: res.send is not a function
    at rp.then.catch.err (/srv/index.js:22:14)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at tryCatcher (/srv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/srv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/srv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/srv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/srv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:695:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/srv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/srv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/srv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/srv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
```

Comment: If you have a solution you should add it as an answer instead of putting it inside your question.

Comment: oh..., sorry I will add it as an answer then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me., using return before promise returns the result from promise, and we need to use `return` when using `functions.https.onCall` and `res.send` when using `functions.https.onRequest` it took me 3 days to get it & no need of adding `json=true` in request-promise options when your url returns a json, it just made things complicated

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const rp = require('request-promise');

exports.fetch = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {

    const url = req.url + '&key=MY_API_KEY';
    var options = {
        uri: url, // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
    };

    return rp(options)
    .then(result => {
        console.log('here is response: ' + result);
        return result;
    }).catch(err => {
        // API call failed...
        return err;
    });

})
```

Comment: Glad that you found the solution. Note that error handling with HTTPS Callable Cloud Functions is a bit different than error handling for "standard" Cloud Functions, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

Answer (score 2):

You should use promises, in your Cloud Function, to handle asynchronous tasks (like the call to the URL). By default **request** does not return promises, so you need to use an interface wrapper for request, like [**request-promise**](https://github.com/request/request-promise).

The following adaptations should do the trick:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

exports.fetch = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {

  const url = req.url + '&key=MY_API_KEY';
  console.log(url);

  var options = {
    uri: url,
    json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
  };

  rp(options)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Get response: ' + response.statusCode);
      res.send(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // API call failed...
      res.status(500).send('Error': err);
    });

})
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering but when i try to deploy function with your code it is giving out `non zero exit code 1` so I replaced res.send with return and then it deployed, now I need to test if it works

Comment: again it returns null value

Comment: You must finish your HTTP Cloud Function with res.send. You may watch the following official video about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA. You should modify your question by adding the entire code of your Function, in order for us to try your code and reproduce the error.

Comment: ok i have replaced it again with res.send now i am getting this error `error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return`

Comment: updated code with complete function code please help me

Comment: Actually this message is not really an error, but rather a linter warning. As you will see in the video I refer to in the comment above, you should terminate an HTTP Function with `res.send()`. Here is a SO answer that indicates a way to solve that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554293/firebase-cloud-functions-each-then-should-return-a-value-or-throw-promise-al. I've not tried it however. You will find a lot of answers for this Linter problem: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Each+then%28%29+should+return+a+value+or+throw+promise+

Comment: hi.., @Renaud Tarnec I have made some modifications to the function code by adding return before res.send(result) so as to avoid linter warnings and deployed the function with out any error but still it is returning null value when I call it from my app

Comment: What happens if you log the response `console.log(response)` (or `result`, since it seems you use this variable name instead of `response`) and look at the result in the Cloud Function console?

Comment: at last found the solution thanks a lot @Renaud Tarnec